# Can't read Heart Rate in Xiaomi Band 2

Tags: android, bluetooth, xiaomi

I was trying to read Heart Rate values from my Xiaomi Band 2. For this I tried using and adapting BluetoothLeGatt project from https://github.com/android/connectivity-samples/tree/master/BluetoothLeGatt .

So far I was able to survey the BLE devices nearby. After that I selected Xiaomi Band 2 and I could successfully list out all the services this device had, including Heart Rate Service. Inside Heart Rate Service I found the characteristic Heart Rate Measurement that I was looking for.

I tried to print data from this characteristic without success. I was unable to see any data in my log, even though I made some slight changes.

This is my LEScanCallback (with the slight changes done)

```
    // Implements callback methods for GATT events that the app cares about.  For example,
    // connection change and services discovered.
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }

            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic =
                            gatt.getService(HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID)
                            .getCharacteristic(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_CHAR_UUID);

            System.out.println("HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_CHAR_UUID: "+HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_CHAR_UUID);
            /*gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true);

            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG_UUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
            gatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor); */

            setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic,true);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
            }

            System.out.println("onCharacteristicRead: " + Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));

        }

        @Override
        public void onDescriptorWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor, int status){
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status);

            System.out.println("onDescriptorWrite");
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic = gatt.getService(HEART_RATE_SERVICE_UUID)
                    .getCharacteristic(HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT_CHAR_UUID);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            characteristic.setValue(new byte[]{1, 1});
            //gatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic);
            boolean success = gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
            System.out.println("success? "+success);
            System.out.println("status: "+status);

        }


        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);

            System.out.println("onCharacteristicChanged: " + Arrays.toString(characteristic.getValue()));

        }
    };
```

I don't get to the point onCharacteristicRead() or onCharacteristicChanged() is called. I believe it's because gatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic) is FALSE and status is 3 (GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED) in onDescriptorWrite() function.

Can somebody help me figuring out the problem? I'm starting to lose all hope...

Comment: Unclear if you are basing your work off of this article: https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/how-i-hacked-xiaomi-miband-2-to-control-it-from-linux-a5bd2f36d3ad

Comment: I'm basing from the git repo I shared (BluetoothLeGatt). That article mentions changing smartphone to dev mode and I hoped I could avoid that

Comment: If you are installing your app to a phone via `adb`, that phone is already in "dev mode".

Comment: The idea is that users install it from the play store

Comment: Building an app that is installable from the Play Store should be possible. The article I linked to is for reverse engineering the protocol used by Xiaomi Band 2 and has links to open source projects in Python. You'll have to follow what was discovered, i.e. the Authentication step, as most bluetooth devices add a proprietary layer.